# Getting first item in jsonp object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working with a jsonp object, it lists items like this:

```
    {

"played_tracks": [
    {
        "artist": {
            "id": 5524,
            "name": "BAAUER",
            }
        },
        "title": "Harlem Shake",
    },
    {
        "artist": {
            "id": 114,
            "name": "BIRDY",
            }
        },
        "title": "Wings ",
    },
    {
        "artist": {
            "id": 1257,
            "name": "MILEY CYRUS",
            }
        },
        "title": "Wrecking Ball",
    },
    {
etc........
```

Now currently I'm using this code to loop through all of them:

```
            for(i in json.played_tracks)
        {
            oTrack = json.played_tracks[i];
         etc.........

        }
```

How do I adjust my code to only display the last played song? The last song is the first item in the jSONP object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looping over `json.playedTracks`, just fetch the first item of the array like so:

```
oTrack = json.playedTracks[0];
```

As you say, the first item is the "last played track," so that should do what you want. If you need the other end of the list though, you can grab that element just as easily:

```
oTrack = json.playedTracks[json.playedTracks.length - 1];
```

Comment: +1, but if you don't give a damn about the array `json.playedTracks.pop()` may be a shorter wording ;)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I get an error now with my oTrack though: "TypeError: oTrack is undefined".
only thing I changed was replace the "i" by "0" and remove the for loop, any idea why I'm getting this error now?

It still works if I don't remove the "for(i in json.played_tracks)" loop part, but now I have 5 times the same item :p